# Сворачивающееся при скролле меню

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, menu, header

Задача: сделать меню, которое при скролле сворачивается в бургер. Попробовала сделать через JQuery и добавление/удаление классов. Код работает, но при перезагрузке страницы, если мы находимся не в самом её верху, примерно 1 раз из 5 меню пояляется открытым и снова скрывается, как только начинаем скроллить. Как это исправить? Нужно, чтобы открытым оно было только наверху.

```
<header class="header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header__body">
                    <a href="#" class="header__logo">
                        <img src="assets/img/logo_1.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="header__burger">
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="header__menu">
                        <ul class="header__list">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="header__link active">Главная</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="header__link">Карта</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#history" class="header__link">История</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#gallery" class="header__link">Галерея</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#shop" class="header__link">Айдентика</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#contacts" class="header__link">Контакты</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
</header>
```

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1; }
  .header:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 2; }
  .header__body {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
    height: 114px;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center; }
    .header__body.scroll {
      -webkit-box-pack: end;
          -ms-flex-pack: end;
              justify-content: flex-end; }
  .header__logo {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 100px;
            flex: 0 0 100px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3; }
    .header__logo img {
      max-width: 100%; }
    .header__logo.hidden {
      top: -100%; }
  .header__burger {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 30px;
    height: 20px;
    z-index: 3; }
    .header__burger:before, .header__burger:after {
      content: '';
      background-color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(145, 124, 125, 0.5), 5px 5px 10px rgba(222, 192, 193, 0.5);
              box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(145, 124, 125, 0.5), 5px 5px 10px rgba(222, 192, 193, 0.5); }
    .header__burger:before {
      top: 0; }
    .header__burger:after {
      bottom: 0; }
    .header__burger.work:before {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
              transform: rotate(45deg);
      top: 9px; }
    .header__burger.work:after {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
              transform: rotate(-45deg);
      bottom: 9px; }
    .header__burger span {
      background-color: #fff;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      left: 0;
      top: 9px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(145, 124, 125, 0.5), 5px 5px 10px rgba(222, 192, 193, 0.5);
              box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(145, 124, 125, 0.5), 5px 5px 10px rgba(222, 192, 193, 0.5); }
    .header__burger.work span {
      -webkit-transform: scale(0);
              transform: scale(0); }
    .header__burger.sticky {
      display: block; }
  .header__menu.hidden {
    top: -100%;
    display: inline;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 30%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(97, 76, 77, 0.7);
    padding: 120px 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s; }
    .header__menu.hidden .header__link.active {
      font-weight: normal; }
  .header__menu.work {
    top: 0; }
  .header__list {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2; }
    .header__list.right {
      display: block;
      text-align: left; }
      .header__list.right li {
        margin: 0 0 20px 0; }
  .header__link {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    margin: 0 30px 0 30px;
    -webkit-transition: text-shadow 0.5s;
    transition: text-shadow 0.5s; }
    .header__link:hover {
      text-shadow: 0.5px 0px 0px #F2F2F2, -0.5px 0px 0px #F2F2F2; }
    .header__link.active {
      font-weight: 600; }
    .header__link.big {
      font-size: 24px; }
```

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    var height = $('.header__body').height();

    if ($(this).scrollTop() > height ) {
       $('.header__logo').addClass('hidden')
       $('.header__menu').addClass('hidden');
       $('.header__burger').addClass('sticky');
       $('.header__body').addClass('scroll');
       $('.header__list').addClass('right');
       $('.header__link').addClass('big');
    }
    else {
       $('.header__logo').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.header__menu').removeClass('hidden');
       $('.header__burger').removeClass('sticky');
       $('.header__body').removeClass('scroll');
       $('.header__list').removeClass('right');
       $('.header__link').removeClass('big');
       $('.header__burger,.header__menu').removeClass('work');
    }
});
```

Comment: ну если я верно понял - то изначально надо сделать меню в кнопку а при scroll удалить class который отвечает за открытие и закрытие

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/JjGPEoZ вот примерно

Comment: Да, так и сделано. Сложность в том, что, если прокрутить страницу ниже меню, до того момента, когда оно уже убралось в кнопку, а потом нажать обновить, то может снова появиться меню.

Comment: ну тогда по дефолту показать его

Comment: вот щас я исправил - проверьте ссылку